# Configure & control Windows Media Player with Global Hot Keys similar to what Winamp has

Tags: windows-xp, music, windows-media-player

I am habituated to use Winamp for my music needs. Now, I am using Windows Media Player, as I can not install Winamp on my office machine. I want to be able to control Play/Pause, Stop, Next, Previous, Volume Up/Dowm with keyboard irrespective of having or not having focus on Windows Media Player.

Is there any way to do it? Prefer not to install any extra software. I am using Windows XP and WMP 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Media Player doesn't support global hot keys like Winamp does; but there’s a great solution at SourceForge.net named [WMP Keys](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/).

> WMP Keys is global hot keys support
>   addon for Windows Media Player. WMP
>   Keys is easy to use and manage.
>   Download and install it. The next time
>   you open up Windows Media Player, open
>   up the Tools menu, choose Options and
>   the Plugins tab. Find the Backgrounds
>   category and enable the Wmpkeys plugin
>   with a check in its check-box.
>
> At this point, you can choose the
>   Properties button to change any of the
>   hotkeys that are assigned to the Media
>   Player functions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this. (and accept your answer as soon as it works)